# Strange issue: delay of updating data on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, networking, shared-hosting

We develop a football mobile app to show football livescore, match history, topscorer for some leagues in Europe. It is using our backend server as a data provider.

We deploy the backend on a client hosting (placed in America) and point the app to that backend. The backend side works properly, data return exactly as we want (no problem with backend data), but we face issues with updating data on client devices. We and our client live in other countries, we are in Asia and he is in Africa. we are using the same app (download from google play where he published it). Our devices return live data but some of his devices' data is delayed about random 10~40 minutes. I thought that is network problem, but his connection is strong, he can make a video call to me (from Africa to Asia) and the call's quality is very good. Now I'm confused.

I hope that my question will be helpful for others and it won't be closed, as I'm not quite sure where to ask for advice on this matter. I'm really appreciated if you can help me to find the way to detect what cause the issue.

Comment: `the call's quality is very good` because the server host this video call is good not your sever

Comment: Ask him to *ping* your server to check the delay from his location

Comment: Maybe your server has some problem in 'Push' and 'Get' live data.